# How to add inline style to a video/gif embed code that is not part of the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have various embed codes from different gif/video sites eg

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/122375452?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Each site has different ways of embedding eg `<iframe>, <a>, <div>` etc for the opening tag. All I need to do is add inline style to the first tag in the embed code. I thought of registering the element etc but that will fail as it will create outer tags etc. How can I achieve what I want dynamically preferably in jquery but javascript is ok. Ie The embed code will be placed in a input field and onpaste I need to insert the style then display the element. Is using regex my only option?

Comment: What type of styling are you trying to add? The results could vary quite a bit depending on the matchup of embed type (iframe, div, etc) and style attributes (position, float, border, color, ...) etc.

Comment: Hi. I want to add position:absolute;width:100%; etc the gif sites I tested I was able to insert this manually and override any other styles that were present already so I figured I could do it

Comment: The thing is I tried setting a container with `position:relative; height:300px;` wrapping a div with `position:absolute;height;100%width:100%;` but the style from the inserted element is still there, so like you said the codes with set widths etc still display incorrectly

Comment: I say regex is the only way, checking for those tags and taking the first match I would say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tough thing is that if your embed works through an `<iframe>`, the content is not there before it is in the DOM, and it is the content of the iframe that you need to manipulate (some other types of embeds inject directly into your DOM, those should be easier to add style to before attaching).

This may work:

```
var embedCode = '<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/122375452?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>';
var embed = $(embedCode);
embed.on('load', function() {
    // The contents are loaded. add the styles however you choose
    embed.contents().find('body').css({
        width: '100%';
        // etc...
    });
});
// now add the iframe to your dom
$('#myEmbedContainer').append(embed);
```

In your question you mention using regex - I suspect you mean either to detect if it is an iframe embed, or to look into the contents of the loaded iframe. In case 1 (detect if your embed code has an iframe tag), it is probably ok. In case two, I would not try to use regex on a full document in an iframe. Jquery selectors can help you find various wrappers inside the iframe, and that's probably a better way to go. For example:

```
var styleRecipient = embed.contents().find('body');
if (!styleRecipient.length) {
    styleRecipient = embed.contents().children('div').first();
    // etc.
}
```

This is a complicated problem, and I would focus on making it work one embed source at a time. Good luck!

Comment: Can I add embed contents dynamically to the `embedCode` var? Ie `onpaste if ($('my-input').val()) { var embedCode = $('my-input').val()...}` ?

Comment: Yes, just make sure you make an element out of the string afterword doing something like in the answer: `var embed = $(embedCode);`.

Comment: Also note, if the embed code is a simple element (not an `<iframe>`), you can add styles to it right away without waiting for load. But watch out for `<script>` tags in normal elements - they sometimes add an `<iframe>` to the embed after the fact.

Comment: so `'body'` is the body of the element then list the css i want to add and it will add to the element?

Comment: Only probably - most iframes load in a full document/html/head/body etc. If they do, then `embed.contents().find('body')` will be that body element. You could also find the first `<div>` inside the body using `embed.contents().find('body div').first()`, but that's not guaranteed to be there. iframes really contain their own mini-page, so it can have anything. But `'body'` is a good bet. You can inspect a loaded embed in your browser dev tools to see what's actually in there.

Comment: Sorry I am not sure I am understanding this as the element will already be rendered then you are going in and getting its attributes and styling them. I really need to do this before it is in the DOM?

Comment: You can't if it's an iframe. The contents are not there yet to manipulate, and the thing you have to manipulate is the thing that's missing until it's in the DOM. The `.on('load', ...)` in the answer will attach the styles as soon as possible, right after render.

Comment: Sorry man I get it now.  I like this answer and I can just add my extra code before in a function. I will mark as right. Thank you!